# mauron85 background-geolocation installation issues (react-native: command not found)

Tags: reactjs, installation, geolocation, react-native

hope you can help. I'm trying to install mauron85 react-native-background-geolocation and when i go to link the dependencies (react-native link react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation) i keep getting 'react-native: command not found'. i've installed npm, nodejs, react native (npm install -g react-native-cli), flow, watchman and the mauron85 package. i'm running this on ubuntu and have tried on mac and getting the same error message on both. I've also tried doing the manual setup for android and this hasn't worked because I don't have some of the node modules it needs, and have tried adding the right path to my path variable, which has made no difference. Is there anything obvious I'm missing that I've forgotten to install/has anyone had a similar message before?

Thanks!

Comment: you tried with sudo?